# auto increment string by 1 does not work after 1000

Tags: sql-server

I am using this query to auto increment string by 1

```
Select Concat('BS-00',Max(stuff([ProjectN], 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', [ProjectN])-1, ''))+1)
From [dbo].[ProjectInfo]
```

so let's say my current

```
[ProjectN]='BS-00995'
```

I expect the next ProjectN to be BS-00996
but after BS-001000 I got always BS-001000
Why is that and how can I fix it

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include [proper sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and expected results.

Comment: If projectn is string then the max of projectn is 999 and with that being the case then 999 + 1 is 1000 (always)

Comment: Often, for stuff like this, is can be "better" to store the numerical and prefix parts in separate columns with the correct datatypes and then use a (`PERSISTED`) computed column. Then you don't have issues like `'999' + '1' = '9991'` or `'1000' > '999' = FALSE`, as the numerical suffix would be stored as a numerical data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult without test data, but my guees is that using `MAX()` with numbers, stored as text, does not work as you expect. The following statement reproduces this issue:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        'BS-00',
        MAX(STUFF([ProjectN], 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [ProjectN]) - 1, '')) + 1
    )
FROM (VALUES
    ('BS-00998'),
    ('BS-00999'),
    ('BS-001000')
) ProjectInfo (ProjectN)
```

One possible solution is to use `CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        'BS-00',
        MAX(CONVERT(int, STUFF([ProjectN], 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [ProjectN]) - 1, ''))) + 1
    )
FROM (VALUES
    ('BS-00998'),
    ('BS-00999'),
    ('BS-001000')
) ProjectInfo (ProjectN)
```